# Apostrophe cms - inline editing of rich text in custom widgets?

Tags: node.js, apostrophe-cms

I can't make inline editing of rich text save back to the db in some cases.

Please bear with me, there will be some code pasted here, as it is the only way I can describe what I'm doing.

I have two kinds of custom widgets in my project - the ones where there is only one instance of the widget, typically defined like this in the `lib\modules` directory:

```
article-widgets
    - views
    -    - widget.html
    - index.js
```

And then the kind of widgets that are repeated, and can be used in several places around the site, typically defined like this:

```
employees
    - index.js
employees-widgets
    - views
    -    - widget.html
```

**This one I can make work:**

In the first kind I define a rich text are in `article-widgets\index.js`

```
{
    name: 'ingress',
    label: 'Ingress',
    type: 'area',
    required: true,
    options: {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `article-widgets\views\widget.html`

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.widget, 'ingress', 'apostrophe-rich-text',{
    toolbar: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
}) }}
```

**This one is not working for me:**

In the second type - I can edit inline, but changes are not saved.

In `employees\index.js`

```
{
    name: 'body',
    label: 'Beskrivelse',
    type: 'area',
    options: {
        widgets: {
            'apostrophe-rich-text': {
                toolbar: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `employees-widgets\views\widget.html`

```
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
    <div>
        {{
            apos.singleton(piece, 'body', 'apostrophe-rich-text', {
                toolbar: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Link', 'Unlink' ]
            })
        }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't understand why the later is not working. Am I doing something wrong - or is inline editing of repeated items not possible?

Answer (score 0):

One of Apostrophe's subtleties is that any property beginning with an underscore (_) (*except _id*) is **not actually part of the parent object** and changes don't go back to the database

These are properties attached for convenience by Apostrophe somewhere in the retrieval process.

I don't thinkg modifying the piece from the widget is something baked in by default (typically piece-widgets are single-serving views for content) but it is possible to set up custom backend functionality.

Not a total 1:1 of your issue but if you look at the `comments` and `comments-widgets` module in this (rough) example, you can see we're modifying the piece's content via the widget.

https://github.com/stuartromanek/apostrophe-comment-system/tree/master/lib/modules

Comment: Actually, this should work — the fact that the pieces were loaded as an underscored property doesn't prevent you from editing an area in one of them inline. Would you please check what version of the Apostrophe module you have or just use "npm update" to eliminate that as a possible issue? Changes were recently made to improve handling of inline editing of fields that are also present in the modal dialog box.

Comment: Hey @boutell thanks for the correction, can you just post a real Answer to this Q so i can delete this fake news, thanks

Comment: Hey @boutell - I did an npm update and I'm now on Apostrophe 2.33.1 - however it is still not working.

Comment: Hmm, that ought to work. Can you provide a link to a fork of our sandbox project (or another project it's OK to share with us) demonstrating the problem so I can hack on that a little?

Comment: Hi @boutell - I created a new apostrophe project and copied the employee widgets I'm using in my project in there - and added them to app.js and home.html

https://github.com/trondulseth/aph-test

Now when trying to add an employee in this new test project I get an error saying "You were unable to take control of the document" when trying to add an image or rich text field..... not sure why.

Comment: Sorry about that one @trondulseth, hit that with another npm update? We released a fix this morning for the short-lived but nasty bug you just mentioned.

Comment: Bug gone :) So now you can see my initial observation. If you try to add an employee (Ansatt in the menu - norwegian). And then add the widget for viewing employees on the main page - you'll observe that any inline changes made to the description field of the employee is not saved to the database (it's not looking good since I've not included any css into the barebones example - but you'll see what I mean)

Comment: Sorry for the slow response... yes, editing this inside a widget appears not to work so far. I will add a ticket on this.

Comment: @boutell - is there any news on this? :)