# Editor controls load

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm currently developing a website in apostrophe when I came across this bug:

[Apostrophe cms - inline editing of rich text in custom widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884189/apostrophe-cms-inline-editing-of-rich-text-in-custom-widgets)

The workaround that occurred to me was to create the piece as a simple widget, then and then add them in a apostrophe-page. To access to the widget like a piece using a slug, I intercept the request in the apostrophe-express, then load the widget querying the database and I render a view which includes widget.html.

This works pretty well, the only problem is that the editing controls are not loaded, so I can only edit them in the apostrophe-page.

I searched the source code of some modules, pages, widgets, pieces, pieces-pages trying to find where the editor controls where loaded but I had no luck.

I was wondering if anybody had a similar problem or knows how to load the controls can help me a little bit with this.

Thanks!

Comment: We've opened a real ticket for this bug. It should work the way you'd hope https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/issues/1343

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this original problem has been patched in `master` and will land in the npm registry next publish.

https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll wait a few days then!

Comment: May you have an ETA for the next publish?

Comment: Usually on Fridays, http://forum.apostrophecms.org/ will get updated. You could also check out the Gitter for faster updates

Comment: Published http://forum.apostrophecms.org/t/apostrophe-2-54-2-2-54-3-contextual-editing-of-pieces-in-widgets-better-migration-handling/446